# CSS circular ripple animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to get the semi circle upwards ripple effect and here is what I have so far. I have this wifi beam animation but I need the same similar effect on semicircle with solid color beams. Any help would be appreciate.

Rather than flickering effect, I need smooth moving animation for website banner.

**[What I have so far](http://jsbin.com/poxejunuhi/edit?html,css,output)**

```
<div class="wifi-symbol">
  <div class="wifi-circle first"></div>
  <div class="wifi-circle second"></div>
  <div class="wifi-circle third"></div> 
  <div class="wifi-circle fourth">
</div>
```

And here is the reference image for animation.

[image]

Comment: You've spelled `opacity` wrong on most of the keyframes.

Comment: Not entirely clear the effect you are after, so before I answer is this the sort of animation you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/v4t0u83p/

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, within your question, not a jsbin. [mcve] That site can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```css
body {
  background: #232425;
}
.wifi-symbol {
  --color: #ffffcc;
  --opacity: 0.4;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
}
.wifi-symbol > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%);
  border-color: var(--color);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: expansion 3s infinite;
}
.wifi-symbol > :nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}
.wifi-symbol > :nth-child(2) {
  width: 72.5%;
  height: 145%;
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.wifi-symbol > :nth-child(3) {
  width: 45%;
  height: 90%;
}
.wifi-symbol > :nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
  height: 20%;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: var(--color);
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes expansion {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: var(--opacity);
  }
}

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 0 !important; }
```

```html
<div class="wifi-symbol"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: How can I make those waves solid white color? currently it is semi transparent

Comment: @user6725932 by changing the `border-color` (and adjusting the opacity in the keyframes to your liking)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea with one element but without transparency:

```css
.ripple {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border-right:20px solid red;
 border-top:20px solid red;
 border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
 border-left:20px solid transparent;
 
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0 20px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 40px red inset,
            0px 0px 0 60px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 80px red inset;
 
 border-radius:50%;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 position:relative;
 animation:pulse 2s infinite linear;
}
.ripple:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to top right,#fff 50%,transparent 50%);
  z-index:1;
}

@keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-top-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0 20px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 40px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset,
            0px 0px 0 60px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 80px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset;
 }
 25% {
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-top-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0 20px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 40px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset,
            0px 0px 0 60px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 80px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
 
 }
 50% {
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-top-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0 20px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 40px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) inset,
            0px 0px 0 60px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 80px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset;
 
 }
 75% {
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0 20px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 40px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset,
            0px 0px 0 60px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 80px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset;
 
 }
 100% {
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-top-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0 20px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 40px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset,
            0px 0px 0 60px #fff inset,
            0px 0px 0 80px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) inset;
 
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple">

</div>
```

With transparency you may try this:

```css
.ripple {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 border-right:20px solid red;
 border-top:20px solid red;
 border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
 border-left:20px solid transparent;
 
 border-radius:50%;
 transform:rotate(-45deg);
 position:relative;
 animation:pulse 3s 2s infinite linear;
}
.ripple:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
  border:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
  animation:pulse 3s 1s infinite linear;
}
.ripple:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:60px;
  top:60px;
  left:60px;
  right:60px;
  border:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
  animation:pulse 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,33%,100% {
    border-right:20px solid red;
    border-top:20px solid red;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
  }
  66% {
    border-right:20px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    border-top:20px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="ripple">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The example you posted in your JSBin makes clever use of borders in divs to create a circular shape using border-radius, then clip it with the container, and finally rotate the result to make a top-down wifi-symbol.

Try adapting the borders and border radius to your liking until you have a semi-circle instead of a quarter-circle.

Comment: In theory your answer is correct, but please provide an example displaying your solution. As it stands this would have been an excellent comment, but its a bit to short to be considered an answer.

Comment: Yes indeed, should I remove the answer and put it in a comment?

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)